# Convert python script to executable in windows

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I was trying to convert a python script to download outlook emails to an executable. I was using cx_Freeze. The setup file be given below. I am getting the error "The breadability distribution was not found"[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGq0k.png)

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sumy

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "appdirs", 
"packaging.version","packaging.specifiers", "packaging.requirements"], 
"excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
  base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("EmailSummary.py", base=base)])
```

Any idea for trouble shooting. I am using python 3.6.3.

Comment: Did you try installing breadability? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/breadability

Comment: I found the solution. It has nothing to do with breadability. It was some problem with an unused package in my code.  I removed all unused packages, it worked. I have no idea why.